# Script in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am completely new to RunDeck, please tell how to run a script(Python/shell script) via RunDeck?

Say I have a Python script which runs command print ("Hello Rundeck") or I have a shell script which runs command echo "Hello Rundeck". Please tell me how to run these scripts from RunDeck?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a job

[image: Create a job]

Then choose to add a "Execute remote command" step

[image: Add step]

And define your command

[image: Define command]

Of course you will need yo have properly configured your rundeck first, with appropriates nodes, etc

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question is still of interest, but another way to run any command ad hoc is going to the 'Commands' menu, choosing the script name and the node to run the script to.